# How to run shellscript parallely like java thread

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Hi I have a script mainscript.sh
In main script I have multiple chile script.

```
child1.sh  
child2.sh  
child3.sh 
rm -rf /home/bdata/batch/*
```

I am running my mainscript.sh which will run all child jobs in parallel.

**mainscript.sh**

```
child1.sh &
child2.sh &
child3.sh &
rm -rf /home/bdata/batch/*
```

4th statement runs before completing all the execution.

Is there any way I can control the execution of last line after finishing above  3 scripts in parallel.

Comment: Add & at the end for each script. If you want to run irrespective of terminal then go for nohup option.

Comment: Perl supports multithreading and forking if that's an acceptable solution. I know it's not quite shell, but is nearly as ubiquitous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons/26297240#26297240

Comment: @Kate --That works but the problem is I want to run the last line after all other shell script finished execution.In my case it is deleting my folder before finishing all the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply tell the shell to wait until the children are all dead:

```
child1.sh &
child2.sh &
child3.sh &
wait
rm -rf /home/bdata/batch/*
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
./child1.sh &
./child2.sh & 
./child3.sh &
```

Use `./` or full path to the script.

If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell
executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does
not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0. If you want to execute all child-scripts before exiting the script then add `wait` at the end (as @Mark Setchell wrote below).

Comment: Add `wait` at the end if you want to wait till all children finish before exiting the script.