# Adding Key/Value To Hash(Perl)

Tags: json, multithreading, perl

Hi I'm trying to add multiple keys/values into a hash. Basically file names and their data. Each of the json file's content have hash and array referencing. The hash that contains the file names and data will be handled else where.

This is my code:

```
 sub getDecode {
    my $self = shift;
    my @arrUrls = ('http://domain.com/test.json', 'http://domain.com/test_two.json', 'http://domain.com/test3.json');

    my $resQueue = Thread::Queue->new();
    my $intThreads = 10;
    my @arrThreads = ();
    my %arrInfo = ();

    foreach my $strUrl (@arrUrls) {
          for (1..$intThreads) {
              push (@arrThreads, threads->create(sub {
                          while (my $resTask = $resQueue->dequeue) {
                                      my $resData = get($strUrl);
                                      my $strName = basename($strUrl, '.json');
                                      my $arrData = decode_json($resData);
                                      $arrInfo{$strName} = $arrData;
                          }
              }));
          }
   }

   $resQueue->enqueue(@arrUrls);
   $resQueue->enqueue(undef) for 1..$intThreads;
   $_->join for @arrThreads;

  return %arrInfo;       
  }
```

When I try data dumping on `%arrInfo` no output is given. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're multithreading and not sharing the variable. When a thread spawns, the existing variable-space is cloned - so each thread has it's own local copy of `%arrInfo` which is discarded when it exits.

You need to:

```
use threads::shared;
my %arrInfo : shared;
```

You're also doing something a bit odd with your thread spawn loop - you're spawning 10 threads x 3 URLs - for 30 threads, but only queuing 3 URLs to process. But then you're also not actually using `$resTask` at all, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

So I'm prepared to bet your code hangs at the end, because you're trying to join some threads that aren't complete.

You might find `$resQueue -> end()` is more suitable than queuing up `undef`.

Example using a shared hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use Data::Dumper;

my %test_hash : shared;
my %second_hash;

$test_hash{'from_parent'}       = 1;
$second_hash{'from_parent_too'} = 1;

threads->create(
    sub {
        $test_hash{'from_first'}       = 2;
        $second_hash{'from_first_too'} = 2;
    }
);
threads->create(
    sub {
        $test_hash{'from_second'}       = 3;
        $second_hash{'from_second_too'} = 3;
    }
);

foreach my $thr ( threads->list() ) { $thr->join }

print Dumper \%test_hash;
print Dumper \%second_hash;
```

For a 'worker threads' style approach, I'd offer: [Perl daemonize with child daemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons/26297240#26297240)

Comment: There's actually more urls but I removed them. Thank you though :)

Comment: You're still spawning 10 threads per URL, and it looks like 9 of those will be redundant.

Comment: Just a question, it keeps saying "invalid value for shared scalar"

Comment: Not sure why. My test case works ok. Which line gives that error? (And are you still assigning an empty array to `%arrInfo` because that's redundant)

Comment: Could you show me how you're doing it, if you dont mind?

Comment: Edited answer with example