# Perl polling a file handle?

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'SnPmaster.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {   
    print $line;    
    last if $. == 2;
}

close $info;
```

Everywhere i look, the above is recommended to read from a file handle (`while( my $line = <$info>)`).

But is there a way to read instead of using a while loop?

```
open FH,
    "executable_that_prints_every_once_in_awhile"
    or die 'Cannot open FH';
while (1){
    # do something which doesnt get blocked by <FH>

    if (my $line from <FH>) {           <---- is there something like it?
        print $line;
    }

    last if eof <FH>;
}
```

For example, polling to see if there is an input from a file handle?

The problem with `while( my $line = <$info>)` is that it blocks so i cant do other things while waiting to get something from a FH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. You need [`IO::Select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html) and the `can_read` function.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use IO::Select;

my $selector = IO::Select->new();

open( my $program, "-|", "executable_that_prints_every_once_in_awhile" );
$selector->add($program);

foreach my $readable_fh ( $selector->can_read() ) {

    #do something with <$readable_fh>
}
```

Or alternatively - parallel code using `threads` or `fork`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use threads;

sub reader_thread { 
   open ( my $program, "-|", "executbale_file" );
   while ( my $line =  <$program> ) {
      print $line;
   }
}

threads -> create ( \&reader_thread );

while ( 1 ) {
   #do something else
}

#sync threads at exit - blocks until thread is 'done'. 
foreach my $thr ( threads -> list ) {
  $thr -> join();
}
```

Generally I would suggest threading when you need to do more than a trivial amount of IPC, and forking for general performance. [`Thread::Queue`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html) is quite a good way of passing data back and forth between threads, for example. (See: [Perl daemonize with child daemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons/26297240#26297240) if you think you want to go that route)

Comment: Or make the handle non-blocking

Comment: i went with your second approach and it works great. thank you