# Parallelizing the Processing of an Array

Tags: perl

```
sub parallelizing{
  my counter = 0; 
  my $MAX_PROCESS = 10;
  my $workerQueue = Parallel::ForkManager->new($MAX_PROCESS);

  $workerQueue->start and next;
    print "$process #" . $counter . " started\n";
    $counter = $counter +1
  $workerQueue->finish;
}
```

I am using [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://metacpan.org/module/Parallel::ForkManager) to create child processes that share the variable `$counter`, but it turns out that it's not shared. Is there any way to let child processes to share a variable?

Comment: You would need to have them talk to the parent process and have the parent assign the element. It may be easier to pre-slice the array and hand chunks to each worker.

Comment: Use [forks::shared](http://p3rl.org/forks::shared) or [threads::shared](http://p3rl.org/threads::shared) if you need to share data.

Comment: That code won't compile for a couple of reasons. Please post the *real* code that you have written and tested

Comment: I intend to parallelize the processing of a big array, and wanted to emulate the problem of changing slice index by the code snippet posted. Now I realize it's easier and enough to pass the changed index from the parent to the child instead of attempting to change it in the child process.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, not that way. `fork` creates a separate process instance, with it's own memory state. It implements a `copy-on-write` mechanism (generally) so it's quite efficient. But processes can't share memory trivially.

However you can do something like `threads::shared` to create a threaded; shared variable accessible by multiple things. (Although I'd normally suggest using `Thread::Queue` instead).

Something like this: 
[Perl daemonize with child daemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons/26297240#26297240)
Might give some useful examples.