# Linux - Perl fork loop without exiting child process

Tags: perl, fork

I'm new to fork concept. I'm trying a simple script with fork loop expecting to execute twice but end up with 3 occurrence. is it because i did not exit the child process ? can you clarify please

script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(my $fh, '>', 'report.txt');
print $fh "before invoke fork \n";
close $fh;

@list = (1, 2);

foreach $a (@list){

    if($pid = fork){
       open(my $fh, '>>', 'report.txt');
       print $fh "Parent process! $a $pid\n";
       close $fh;

    }else {
       open(my $fh, '>>', 'report.txt');
       print $fh "Child process $a $pid\n";
       close $fh;
    }
}
```

output:

before invoke fork
My second report generated by perl 1 1808
My second report generated by perl 2 1809
My thrid report generated by perl 2 0
My thrid report generated by perl 1 0
My second report generated by perl 2 1810
My thrid report generated by perl 2 0

Comment: After the `if-else` both parent and child continue, so they both go for the second iteration. During which you fork again. Print something (to screen) right after `foreach`.

Comment: A comment. This is fun and useful. But it comes with things that one must know (ang with gotchas) and I suggest careful study of literature along with play. Some sources: [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html), [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html), [wait](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html), [waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html), and (at least some of) [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html). Then Perl Cookbook, supposedly "outdated" but also really not -- with _plenty_ of crucial information.  And then there are many modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the point at which you `fork()` both processes start at *exactly the same point*.

So 'child 1' will continue to run, and continue through the loop, and run 'iteration 2'.

So parent will fork twice, child 1 will fork once, and child 2 - because it's the last loop iteration - will not fork at all.

I would suggest you really should consider [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Parallel-ForkManager-1.19/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm) because it simplifies this a lot. And also - turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings`. And don't use single letter variables, especially not `$a`.

Here's some [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons) of how to use `Parallel::ForkManager`.

However to address your problem - sticking a `last` in the child stanza will cause it to bail out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! it explains everything

Answer (score 1):

You are not waiting child process in your loop. There is an good explanation about fork in loops here:

http://perlmaven.com/fork

There is a manual too.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html

Try to be careful about all possibilities in a fork. Treat problems matters! A simple, good and recommended way to implement:

```
use strict;
use warning;
use Carp qw/confess/;
my $pid = fork;

if(!defined($pid)){
  confess "\nWhy you hates me, O.S.? Why?\nANSWER: $!\n\n";
}
elsif($pid == 0){
  #Child process. Do something and exit
}
else{
  #Parent process
  waitpid $pid,0; 
}
```

There is another features related that is not described in this example. To read more about it, please checkout the [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html) linked above

Checkout [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) too!

Comment: Thanks Andre for your help !