# Why this Perl script run out of memory gradually

Tags: multithreading, perl, memory-leaks, release, detach

I have a trouble in running a Perl script in muti-threads. It continued consume memory and finally the system ran out of memory and killed it. It seems that the sub-threads were detached but the system resource were not released when they finished. I am pretty new to Perl and couldn't find which part went wrong. This is part of the script that may cause this problem. Could anyone help me with this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "different number:\t";
my $num1=<>;
chomp $num1;
if($num1!~/[1 2 3 4 5]/)
 {
    print "invalid input number\n";
    END;
 }

my $i=0;
my $no;
my @spacer1;
my $nn;
my @spacer2;

open IN,"file1.txt"or die"$!";
  while(<IN>)
   {
     chomp;
     if($_=~ /^>((\d)+)\|((\d)+)/)
       {         
         $no=$1;
         $spacer1[$no][0]=$3;        
       }
     else
       {
         $spacer1[$no][1]=$_;       
       }
   }
close IN;

open IN, "file2.txt" or die "$!";
  while(<IN>)
   {
     chomp;
     if($_=~ /^>((\d)+)\|((\d)+)/)
       {         
         $nn=$1;
         $spacer2[$nn][0]=$3;       
       }
     else
       {
         $spacer2[$nn][1]=$_;       
       }
   }
close IN;

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#create threads
use subs qw(sg_ana);
use threads;
use Thread::Semaphore;


my $cycl=(int($no/10000))+1;
my $c;
my @thd;
my $thread_limit= Thread::Semaphore -> new (3);

foreach $c(1..$cycl)
  {
    $thread_limit->down();
    $thd[$c]=threads->create("sg_ana",$c-1,$c,$num1);
    $thd[$c]->detach();
  }
&waitquit;

#-------------------------------------------------------------#limite threads num
sub waitquit 
  {
    print "waiting\n";
    my $num=0;
    while($num<3)
      {
        $thread_limit->down();
        $num++;
      }         
  }

#---------------------------------------------------------------#alignment
my $n;
my $n1;
my $j;
my $k;
my $l;
my $m;
my $num;#number of match
my $num2=0;;#arrange num



sub sg_ana
  {
    my $c1=shift;
    my $c2=shift;
    $num1=shift;
    open OUT,">$num1.$c2.txt" or die "$!";   
    if($num1==1)
      {
        foreach $n($c1*10000..$c2*10000-1)
          {
            if($spacer2[$n][1])
              {
                my $presult1;
                my $presult2;
                $num2=-1;
                foreach $i(0..19)
                  {
                    $num=0;
                    $num2++;
                    my $tmp1=(substr $spacer2[$n][1],0,$i)."\\"."w".(substr $spacer2[$n][1],$i+1,19-$i);
                    foreach $n1(0..@spacer1-1)
                      {
                        if($spacer1[$n1][1])
                          {
                            my $tmp2=substr $spacer1[$n1][1],0,20;
                            if($tmp2=~/$tmp1/)
                              {
                                $num++; 
                                $presult1.=$n1.",";                
                              } 
                          }
                      }        
                    $presult2=$i+1; 
                    if($num>=4)
                      { 
                        print OUT "\n";
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    close OUT;
    $thread_limit->up();
  }
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? Your `$num1` is never defined, which makes the subroutine of `sg_ana` almost a no-op. (This is something `use warnings` would have warned you about)

Comment: This is just part of the code. Before this part, it reads from files.And I am sure there is no problem for that part.

Comment: Your edited code still has a syntax error. An [mcve] would be helpful here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have checked it. There is no syntax erro now.

Comment: `use subs`? What is this, 1998?

Comment: It seems that it has no meaning. It's a mistake.@melpomene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rule one of debugging perl is enable `use strict;` and `use
   warnings;` and then sort out the errors. Actually, you should
   probably do that first of all, before you even start writing code.
2. You're creating and limiting threads via a Semaphore - but actually
   this is really inefficient because of how `perl` does threads - they
   aren't lightweight, so spawning loads is a bad idea. A better way of doing this is via `Thread::Queue` [a bit like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons/26297240#26297240)
3. Please use 3 arg open and lexical file handles. e.g. `open ( my
   $out, '>', "$num.$c2.txt" ) or die $!;`. You're probably getting
   away with it here, but you have got `OUT` as a  global namespace
   variable being used by multiple threads. That way lies dragons.
4. Don't use single letter variables. And given how you you use `$c`
   then you'd be *far* better off:

   ```
   foreach my $value ( 1..$cycl ) { 
       ##  do stuff
   }
   ```

The same is true of all your *other* single letter variables though - they're not meaningful.

5. You pass `$num` before it's initialised, so it's *always* going to
   be `undef` within your sub. So your actual subroutine is just:

   ```
   sub sg_ana
     {
       my $c1=shift;
       my $c2=shift;
       $num1=shift;
       open OUT,">$num1.$c2.txt" or die "$!";   

       close OUT;
       $semaphore->up();
    }
   ```

Looking at it - I think you *may* be trying to do something with a shared variable there, but you're not actually sharing it. I can't decode the logic of your program though (thanks to having a load of single letter variables most likely) so I can't say for sure.

6. You're calling a subroutine `&waitquit;`. That's not good style -
   prefixing with an ampersand and supplying no arguments does
   something subtly different to just invoking the sub 'normally' - so
   you should avoid it.
7. Don't instantiate your semaphore like this:

   ```
   my $semaphore=new Thread::Semaphore(3);
   ```

That's an indirect procedure call, and bad style. It would be better written as:

```
my $thread_limit = Thread::Semaphore -> new ( 3 );
```

8. I would suggest rather than using Semaphores like that, you'd be far better off *not* `detatch`ing your threads, and just using `join`. You also don't need an array of threads - `threads -> list` does that for you.
9. I can't reproduce your problem, because your sub isn't doing
   anything. Have you by any chance modified it for posting? But a classic reason for perl memory exhaustion when threading is because each thread clones the parent process - and so 100 threads is 100x the memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helps.

Comment: 1. Strict and warnings are used before this part, because I am sure that part is Ok, so I just didn't post them.

Comment: 2 I have noticed that OUT is used among threads, but I don't know how to deal with it.  I will try to change it.

Comment: 3. In `sub sg_ana`, the `$num` is a mistake, actually i modified this part before posting.

Comment: 4. I don't know how to limit the threads number running, and I find Semophores works, so I just use it. I have no idea about which is better. I just want to detach the threads, and arrange the number that runs at the same time.

Comment: I don't know why it uses up memory. I have detached the threads, but it didn't work ?

Comment: If your example code doesn't have the problem, then it's next to impossible for me to figure out what it was.

Comment: I have posted all the code. It worked normally but consumed memory gradually. Maybe I can try `join` rather than `detach`.

Comment: Given you are explicitly waiting for your threads to exit before spawning new ones, then `join` is exactly the mechanism you want to be using. `detatch` is for 'if you just don't care' and if you're in that scenario... you probably don't want to be using threads in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `join` is the exact one I need. It's just that it has been said `detatch` is easier to use, so it tried it first.

Comment: **But a classic reason for perl memory exhaustion when threading is because each thread clones the parent process - and so 100 threads is 100x the memory.** , so does this mean even if I use `join`,the memory exhaustion also happens?

Comment: `join`ing a thread should reclaim the memory. But if you're spawning one-per-instance as you are, then `fork` is the optimal tool. `threads` are better suited to a worker thread model operation where you spawn a fixed number of threads to do N way parallelism.

Comment: I have taken your advice, and followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons/26297240#26297240). It ran for one day now, and the memory   consumption didn't increase a lot. A worker thread model is really an excellent idea.