# perl getstore in thread

Tags: multithreading, perl

In the following script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use threads;
threads->create(sub { 
    my $url = "http://www.example.com/logo.jpg"; 
    my $file = "/var/www/html/logo.jpg"; 
    getstore($url, $file);
    threads->detach();
});
```

when I launch this it doesn't save the image, but if I launch the same code not in thread it works, why?

Comment: why you are using the `threads`.

Comment: I need to run this script for multiple url at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "detach" doesn't do what you'd expect. Detached threads are terminated when the program exits. [From the docs...](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads#DESCRIPTION)

> $thr->detach()
>
> Makes the thread unjoinable, and causes any eventual return value to be discarded. ***When the program exits, any detached threads that are still running are silently terminated.***

You should have gotten a message like this.

```
Perl exited with active threads:
    1 running and unjoined
    0 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
```

Instead of detaching, you should wait until all threads are complete at the end of your program.

```
for my $thread (threads->list(threads::running)) {
    $thread->join;
}
```

---

If all you want is to make parallel HTTP requests, there's no need for threads. [LWP::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Parallel) will probably be more efficient.

Comment: I'd also note - for this sort of model, spawning a new thread per request is a really inefficient way of doing it, and you'd be far better off doing something worker-threads style [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons). But `LWP::Parallel` is probably a better choice in this scenario :)

Comment: I appreciate the tips of @Sobrique. The answer of Schwern is correct, thanks!!