# I need to know how to implement multithreading

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am trying to implement multithread functionality perl script for more speed
I am trying to implement multithread functionality perl script for more speed

I need to know how to implement multithreading for the following perl code

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use if $^O eq "MSWin32", Win32::Console::ANSI;
use Getopt::Long;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use IO::Select;
use HTTP::Headers;
use IO::Socket;
use HTTP::Response;
use Term::ANSIColor;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(GET);
use URI::URL;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::Simple;
use LWP;
use URI;
use JSON qw( decode_json encode_json );
use threads;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua    = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 1);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31");


{
    chomp($site);
    push(@threads, threads->create (\&ask, \&baidu, $site));
    sleep(1) while(scalar threads->list(threads::running) >= 50);
}

eval {
    $_->join foreach @threads;
    @threads = ();
};

########### ASK ###########

sub ask {
    for ( $i = 0; $i < 20; $i += 1) {

        my $url = "https://www.ask.com/web?o=0&l=dir&qo=pagination&q=site%3A*.fb.com+-www.fb.com&qsrc=998&page=$i";

        my $request  = $ua->get($url);
        my $response = $request->content;

        while( $response =~ m/((https?):\/\/([^"\>]*))/g ) {

            my $link = $1;

            my $site = URI->new($link)->host;
            if ( $site =~ /$s/ ) {
                if ( $site !~ /</ ) {   
                    print "ask: $site\n";
                }
            } 
        }
    } 
}


########### Baidu ###########

sub baidu {
    for ( my $ii = 10; $ii <= 760; $ii += 10 ) {

        my $url = "https://www.baidu.com/s?pn=$ii&wd=site:fb.com&oq=site:fb.com";


        my $request  = $ua->get($url);
        my $response = $request->content;

        while ( $response =~ m/(style="text-decoration:none;">([^\/]*))/g ) {
            my $site = $1;
            $site =~ s/style="text-decoration:none;">//g;
            if ( $site =~ /$s/ ) {
                print "baidu: $site\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If run this code I get only Result from `Ask.com`.
How I can fix this problem and thanks for all ?

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop>k.pl -d fb.com
ask: messenger.fb.com
ask: yourbusinessstory.fb.com
ask: research.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: shemeansbusiness.fb.com
ask: nonprofits.fb.com
ask: messenger.fb.com
ask: yourbusinessstory.fb.com
ask: research.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: shemeansbusiness.fb.com
ask: nonprofits.fb.com
ask: politics.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: live.fb.com
ask: messenger.fb.com
ask: yourbusinessstory.fb.com
ask: research.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: shemeansbusiness.fb.com
ask: nonprofits.fb.com
ask: politics.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: live.fb.com
ask: techprep.fb.com
ask: newsroom.fb.com
ask: rightsmanager.fb.com    ask: messenger.fb.com
ask: yourbusinessstory.fb.com
ask: research.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: shemeansbusiness.fb.com
ask: nonprofits.fb.com
ask: politics.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: live.fb.com
ask: messenger.fb.com
ask: yourbusinessstory.fb.com
ask: research.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: shemeansbusiness.fb.com
ask: nonprofits.fb.com
ask: politics.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: live.fb.com
ask: techprep.fb.com
ask: newsroom.fb.com
ask: rightsmanager.fb.com
ask: politics.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: live.fb.com
ask: messenger.fb.com
ask: yourbusinessstory.fb.com
ask: research.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: shemeansbusiness.fb.com
ask: nonprofits.fb.com
ask: politics.fb.com
ask: communities.fb.com
ask: live.fb.com
ask: techprep.fb.com
ask: newsroom.fb.com
ask: rightsmanager.fb.com
```

Comment: [`LWP::Parallel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Parallel)

Answer (score 6):

OK, so first off - there's some really quite icky looking things you're doing here, and I'd suggest you need to step back and review your code. It's looking a bit 'cargo-cult' thanks to things like:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(GET);
```

Or:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua    = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 1);
```

... you're creating a new `LWP::UserAgent` instance, and then ... creating another one with a different parameter.

You've also got a load of errors that you're not seeing because you didn't include the most important `use` items:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw ( all );
```

Turn these on first, and then fix the errors.

But here for example:

```
push(@threads, threads->create (\&ask, \&baidu, $site));
```

What do you think this line is supposed to do? Because what's actually happening here is you try and invoke the `ask` sub, and then pass it arguments of a code reference to `baidu` sub, and a string `$site` - which is undefined at this point in the code. But that's academic, because you NEVER READ THEM in your subroutine.

So it's not really a surprise your code isn't really working - it's nonsense.

But that aside - `perl`s threading model is often misunderstood. It is not a lightweight thread like you might be thinking of in other programming languages - actually it's rather heavyweight.

You're creating and spawning a thread per iteration, and that's not very efficient either.

What you really want to be doing is using `Thread::Queue`.

Spawn a small number of 'worker' threads per task, have them read from the queue, and do their work individually.

`end` the queue when it's done with, and let the threads exit and be reaped by the main process.

Something like in this answer: [Perl daemonize with child daemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons)

... but are you sure there isn't a module that does what you want anyway?